# fdisk and UEFI boot menu showing different locations for Ubuntu EFI partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

Noob here. Just coming back to Linux after being away for ages. Wondering if anyone can explain something possibly very basic for me.

Basically my UEFI environment and fdisk seem to be pointing to different locations for my Ubuntu EFI partition. I'd like to know where my Ubuntu EFI partition lives so that I can try installing different distros without worrying about damaging my windows install.

Setup: dualbooting Windows 11 and Kubuntu on two separate drives. Grub should be installed on the same 2TB drive as Kubuntu. I've run os-prober and its picking up Windows 11 on my other 1TB drive. Can boot into both OSs fine via grub.

Output of fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WD Blue SN570 1TB
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7DA5A408-A3C4-4EA7-89E6-36F940B7E75D

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     239616 1952124927 1951885312 930.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1952124928 1953521663    1396736   682M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 88DA1D58-A2F0-444E-B2A5-FE8DEF2E709D

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 3907028991 3905978368  1.8T Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root: 1.82 TiB, 1997809909760 bytes, 3901972480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-swap_1: 1.91 GiB, 2046820352 bytes, 3997696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Meanwhile this is what my UEFI boot menu shows:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjhN8.jpg)

Can anyone help me figure out why UEFI seems to think Ubuntu boots from the 1TB drive Windows lives on?

Thanks

Comment: Use `lsblk -f` to find out easily which of the ESP's is used by Ubunu, it's the one which is  mounted under `/boot/efi`. If you don't configure explicitely with the `something else` option during install, installer will use first ESP it finds. I think that's what happend and grub is now installed in the ESP of your WIndows disk. Bootloaders will happily coexist in the same ESP, it does not damage your Windows install.

Comment: If you want to use ESP on Linux drive, you can change the UUID used in fstab and totally reinstall grub. `lsblk -f` & `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: @mook765 judging by lsblk -f it looks like you're correct. /boot/efi is mounted to the windows drive. I think I did use the default during install so that makes sense. Does that mean the ESP on my ubuntu drive (/dev/sda1) isn't being used by anything?

Comment: @liquid_state It think so. But to be sure one would have to check the content of the partition.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release? 22.04, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Another problem is that your host system probably will not boot without the ubuntu device (since needed grub files are on it).

Comment: @ubfan1 Hmmm. Wonder if I'm affected. I definitely did target everything during install at /dev/sda and not at /dev/nvme0n1 where windows (and now apparently grub?) live. I'm running kubuntu 23.10. Not sure what installer kubuntu uses. Is there likely to be any harm if I test the theory out by disconnecting my ubuntu drive and seeing if I can boot windows?

Comment: @mook765 AFAICT there's nothing in /dev/sda1. I mounted it and all it contains is a dir called System Volume Information which 'ls -a' shows as being empty.

Comment: @liquid_state There is no harm at all. You can always boot WIndows directly from EFI boot menu since Windows has it's own menu entry which I can see in the picture you provided.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 has a different installer than Ubuntu 22.04, which does not display the noted problem. Can't say which kubuntu23.10 uses, ubiquity is the installer with the problem.

Comment: @ubfan1 sure enough it looks like kubuntu 23.10 is still using ubiquity. I'll add myself to the bug. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @mook765 Also tried booting with /dev/sda physically disconnected. It booted to some flavor of grub with only a shell which I'm guessing is expected behavior. Can still boot windows via the UEFI boot menu. I'll see if I can figure out how to migrate grub over to the correct disk. Thanks for the help.